# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Blender 2.77a GPU render not active

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, 16.04, blender

I run Ubunru Gnome 16.04. My laptop has Nvidia GT 740M and I installed nvidia-364 driver.I installed CUDA-TOOLS 7.5. How can I enable GPU rendering for Blender 2.77a?

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
Memory behind bridge: d2000000-d2ffffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000bfffffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
Memory at d3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
Memory at d3700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
Memory at d3714000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at d3719000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
Memory at d3710000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: d3600000-d36fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=0d, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
Memory behind bridge: d1000000-d1ffffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000d0ffffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
Bus: primary=00, secondary=0e, subordinate=0e, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
Memory behind bridge: d3500000-d35fffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d3400000-00000000d34fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
Memory at d3718000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
I/O ports at 5088 [size=8]
I/O ports at 5094 [size=4]
I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
I/O ports at 5090 [size=4]
I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
Memory at d3717000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
Memory at d3715000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
Memory at d2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at b2000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_364_drm, nvidia_364

07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
DeviceName: Intel(R) Wi-Fi Link 2330
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
Memory at d3600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
Memory at d1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
Memory at d3500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at d3400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Your title and tag say you are using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 but your post says Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: What on Earth... what gave you that output and why is it 95% of your question?

Comment: Sorry man, there s no 16.10. I am a little sleepless. I use 16.04

Comment: @codingman I don t know what s wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you a lot, I fixed it for my GT740M in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

1. Open terminal and type     sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
2. Then I downloaded blender from its site
3. After extracting I opened terminal in that existing folder (right click inside the folder and choose  " Open in Terminal")
4. Type sudo ./blender
5. and ta daaaa, You will have GPU render (User Preferences--->System---->CUDA)

Thank all for help

Answer (score 0):

GPU rendering with Cycles is not enabled by default with Blender. Select Cycles as your rendering engine at the top of your scene, as the default Blender Internal renderer cannot use the GPU.

To enable GPU rendering, go into the User Preferences, and under the System tab, select the Compute Device(s) to use. Next, for each scene, you can configure to use CPU or GPU rendering in the Render properties.

Comment: I made it, but it shows only CPU nor GPU for selecting it :(

Comment: So under "User Preferences" >> "System" tab, the field "Compute Devices" only allows you to select CPU?

Comment: Yes it allows me only CPU :(

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your NVIDIA graphics drivers by first running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

And then running:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-current && sudo apt install nvidia-current-updates
```

According to [Blenders website](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html), you only need shader model 2.0 or above to support Cycles, and according to [Nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), your card supports model 3.0, so that's not the problem.

My laptop has a 650M, and the ability to switch between that and Intel graphics. At one point I had to launch Nvidia control panel and force it to assign Blender to use the Nvidia card, because it was defaulting to the Intel chip. This was under windows, and I don't know if Nvidia provides this switching capability under Linux or not.

Comment: I installed it, I used nvidia-352 driver before installing current ( current is nvidia-304). IN my nvidia-352 driver it showed me Nvidia X-Server with a lot of options. Now there s no options and it uses Intel Graphic card

Comment: @Mehman Jamal, see edit.